# Remove extension and force trailing slash to non trailing slash at end

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hi I have a website in which i am using certain rules to make URLs SEO Friendly. Here is the code :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks    
Options -Multiviews    
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)$ /page1.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)$ /page2.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)$ /page2.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)$ /page2.php?var1=$1 [L,QSA]

# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

It is working fine in some cases but in some cases it is showing some errors.

**Errors i am getting:**

1) Suppose i have a **page3.php** when i go for **www.example.com/page3.php** it shows content of **page3 without removing extension from URL** but when i type **www.example.com/page3** it takes **page3 as a variable and shows content of page2** as i have described a rewrite rule with a single variable for page2.

2) If i write my URL as **www.example.com/var1/** It rewrite URL as **www.example.com/var1/.php** but if i write it as **www.example.com/var1/var2/** It is working fine i.e. removing traling slash.

As mentioned in error 1 first i want to redirect my **.php** pages to **without php** and second if in my URL **www.example.com/page3** *page3 is a file in my root directory it show content of page3 and if page3 is not a file in my root directory then it should take page3 as a variable and it should work as rewrite rule mentioned above*.

For error 2 i want to remove the trailing slash from the URL whether it has 1 variable or 2 or 3 or 4 variables.

Please help me out...Thanks in advance...

***NOTE: I am running my website on HTTPS not on HTTP.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Have redirect rules before rewrite one.
2. Before adding `.php` extension in your .htaccess, check for presence of corresponding `.php` file.

Have it like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]

# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [NE,R=301,L]

# skip all files and directories from rules below
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/([\w-]+)$ page1.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ page2.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ page2.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ page2.php?var1=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Test it after clearing your browser cache fully.